# App crashing when we publish to play store but debug apk works

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm getting following error when I install published apk & it works for debug apk.
While calling the get api app crashing.

Gradle versions

```
id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.0' apply false
```

Retrofit versions

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.10'
```

Error

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  at retrofit2.Utils.methodError (Utils.java:1)
  at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter (HttpServiceMethod.java:56)
  at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations (HttpServiceMethod.java:56)
  at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations (ServiceMethod.java:56)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod (Retrofit.java:1)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke (Retrofit.java:40)
  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke (Proxy.java:1006)
  at $Proxy2.b
  at com.ezytracking.datasources.repo.LoginDataRepository.checkIsValidUser (LoginDataRepository.java:196)
  at com.ezytracking.ui.activities.LoginActivity$1.onClick (LoginActivity.java:196)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7792)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:16112)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7769)
  at android.view.View.access$3800 (View.java:910)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:30218)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8669)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Call return type must be parameterized as Call<Foo> or Call<? extends Foo>
  at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory.get (DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:45)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter (Retrofit.java:33)
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter (Retrofit.java:33)
  at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter (HttpServiceMethod.java:45)
  at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations (HttpServiceMethod.java:45)
  at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations (ServiceMethod.java:45)
```

Comment: Did you add required progurad rules for Retrofit2 and other library while making release apk?

Comment: Following rules added into proguard-rules.pro 
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }

Comment: share more detail about your api calling so it can be traced

Comment: I'm calling API like this  @GET("api/mbLogin/FindUser")
        Call<JsonElement> findUser(@Query("loginame") String page);

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it's look like cause Proguard in release build.
Make sure you've follow document of retrofit about Proguard at this link:

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro

Official retrofit github document:

```
R8 / ProGuard
If you are using R8 the shrinking and obfuscation rules are included automatically.

ProGuard users must manually add the options from retrofit2.pro. You might also need rules for OkHttp and Okio which are dependencies of this library.
```

https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master

Comment: I'm not getting from the above link, but I have already added Proguard rule like this, is there anything different I need to do? -dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.openjsse.**

Comment: @Nayank you should replace all your config about retrofit with config at official document. Then watch result